# UICollectionView different size cell and item count

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

Using `UICollectionView` flow delegate, I'm trying to accomplish this but I still need to remove the huge spacing in the two cell areas.

[image]

My Code :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if indexPath.row == 0  || indexPath.row == 5 {
        return CGSize(width: (getWidth()/2) , height:  (getWidth()/2))
    }
    return CGSize(width: (getWidth()/4) , height: (getWidth()/4))
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```

Expected :

[image]

Comment: what is your getWidth function

Comment: You will need to create your custom collectionViewLayout to get something like that. I don't think that's possible with off the box layout

Comment: try BSJ  promocode

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest
This will help you.

Comment: problem seem like in your getWidth() function check it .  OR Probably in your image constarint not 0

Comment: Can you please post a desired outcome? I have a solution for the layout like [this](https://imgur.com/a/FF4wNVP). Is it the same you want?

Comment: @fewlinesofcode added check my question

Comment: @a.masri check this -> https://octodev.net/custom-collectionviewlayout/

Comment: check your constraints

Comment: @SPatel which constraints

Comment: You can check this video tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7ZZObAj_s8&t=2s

It will be good if you will learn how to make a custom layout in CollectionView. It will help you to design other kinds of layout.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to do this using **plain `UICollectionViewLayout`**. By its nature, `UICollectionViewLayout` is a "line-braking-layout" and line-height is the height of its tallest element. Please see the following:

[Apple docs on using UICollectionViewFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html)

However, the behavior you want can be achieved by subclassing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. Here is a guide on how to do it:

[Creating custom layouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html)